# How do you run multiple instances of Office Communicator?

Tags: windows-7, windows, office-communicator-2007

How can you run multiple instances of Office Communicator at one time?

I tried holding shift, right click, run as administrator but that still brings up the existing instance.

Comment: [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/) should work; possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/43037/running-multiple-instances-of-the-same-application-in-vista

Comment: Tried it, did not work for me (Windows 7 64 Bit),

Answer (score 1):

Worth a shot as to what Eric Johnson said, if there is a different image name in the tasklist then it may run on its own.

Although, if you read the below URL I provided you may find it not being as simple as that

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ocsclients/thread/d68e0661-21d5-40c6-a46b-1f5f9ceeac44/

Answer (score 0):

You might try duplicating the executable for Communicator (keep it in the same directory) and renaming it to something slightly different. Then try starting that one second, or if that doesn't work try starting it first and the original one second.

This approach should work if the method that Communicator uses for detecting a running instance is to look at the process image names, which are based on the exe name.